# Virtual Box Proprietary License

Tags: virtualbox

When installing Virtualbox from the Ubuntu Software Center, it states that the license is "proprietary" and not open source.

When downloading Virtualbox directly from their website, and you go to intstall it, it states the license is "proprietary" also.

How do I find the open source license Virtualbox to install in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

According to the [website](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Licensing_FAQ), VirtualBox is open-source, but its Extension Pack is not - that's probably what the Software Center is referring to.

> 1. **How is VirtualBox licensed?**
>
>    The VirtualBox base package contains the full VirtualBox source code and platform binaries and is licensed under the GNU General Public License, version 2. You can distribute and modify the base package, provided that you distribute all modifications under the GPLv2 as well.
>
>    The VirtualBox Extension Pack is available under the VirtualBox Extension Pack Personal Use and Evaluation License, which is a free license for personal, educational or evaluation use, or an Enterprise License, which is a for-fee license that allows most commercial, non-distribution uses restricted by the PUEL.

Comment: Yup, often a bit confusing; free software implies open source, which implies freedom of access, but does not imply free to use commercially. https://opensource.org/faq#free-software

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Editions for confirmation that Oracle think's it's Open Source, then download it from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Comment: Yes, this is exactly where I downloaded it from. The issue comes after I download it, I open the file in the Ubuntu Software Center, and it shows the license as "Proprietary". Is this just a glitch of some sorts?

Comment: Yes. If the publisher, Oracle, says it's Open Source, it most likely is.

Comment: @ThomasBaker The Software Center has a bug where it does not identify licenses correctly and I have filed one about it.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1778607